# Could not observe events sent to Azure time series insight explorer

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-timeseries-insights

I have configured a time series environment and an event hub to receive data on the time series environment. I have used the simple send java client in [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/samples/Java/Basic/SimpleSend/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/eventhubs/samples/SimpleSend/SimpleSend.java). I can see from the monitoring tab of the time series environment the events are received (using ingress stored events graph). 
I could observe the graphs as shown below:

[image]
[image]

But the problem is that when I go to time series insight explorer I could not observe events that I have sent. It indicates that there are no events.

[image]

Please could you help me to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you had set the event-source for your Azure TSI environment or not. Just for your reference and hope this helps http://learniotwithzain.com/2019/03/near-real-time-iot-data-exploration-using-azure-time-series-insights/